# Regarding REST application ACL

Tags: rest, authorization, acl

I'm trying to look at ways of controlling ACL for REST URIs.

What I'm looking for is

- Define a user
- Define a role
- Define an organization (User owns the org)

Now i would like to dynamically restrict/allow access to resources( REST URI) for authorized users only usin the platforms API.

I know some of the commercial products have such feautres. I'm looking for a (Apache/MIT/BSD/LGPL) licensed open source product which does this.

I've looked at Apache Syncope.It does what i need except for the requirement to control access to RESt URIs. It only treats LDAP and DB connections as resoureces and not REST URIs.

Need to figure out a solution or a tool which would do all this for me.